# How to treat proportions with different sample sizes as response variable in GLM / GLMM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, proportion, prevalence

For an ecological research project, I am trying to model the effect of different factors on the prevalence of a specific pathogen in ticks.

Ticks were collected from around 80 different plots and screened for pathogens. Prevalence is then the proportion of ticks tested positive per site.

Ideally, I would like to use prevalence as the response variable in a GLM or GLMM. It follows a negative binomial distribution. I would then treat this proportion as a count variable (no. of positives out of 100 samples).

However, the number of ticks collected varies across sites. (From 1 to 110)

The prevalence calculated for plots with smaller sample sizes is obviously less reliable compared to plots with larger sample sizes. Is there a way to include a measure of this uncertainty in the analysis?

For now, I excluded all plots with sample sizes < 50, but this doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

Should I try a different modeling approach? I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a binomial GLMM (k/n), don't model this as a Poisson!

Answer (score 0):

A mixed model sounds like a good way to do this.  The sites with fewer observations will be pooled towards the population level estimate and sites with more observations will depart from that estimate.  Here is an example in R

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

#Simulate data

nsites <- 80
sites <- 1:nsites
ticks_sampled <- sample(1:110, replace=T, size=nsites)

# Assume the population prevalence is 20%
# Further assume there is heterogeneity in the prevalence
# between sites.
Z = model.matrix(~factor(sites))
g = rnorm(ncol(Z), 0, 0.25)
logit_p = qlogis(0.2) + Z%*%g
p = plogis(logit_p)
y = rbinom(nsites, ticks_sampled, p)

# Fit the model
d = tibble(sites, ticks_sampled, y)

model = glmer(y~1 + (1|sites) + offset(log(ticks_sampled)), data = d, family = poisson())

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: y ~ 1 + (1 | sites) + offset(log(ticks_sampled))
   Data: d

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   428.3    433.0   -212.1    424.3       78 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0381 -0.5826 -0.1137  0.5330  2.4711 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 sites  (Intercept) 0.039    0.1975  
Number of obs: 80, groups:  sites, 80

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.64026    0.04257  -38.53   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Note our estimate on the log scale is very close to the true value of 20 per 100 samples.  Additionally, a scatter plot of the random effects versus sample size demonstrates this partial pooling effect

[image]

Comment: The offset will take care of the proportionality, but the Poisson cannot get the distribution right. This is a binomial GLMM (k/n)

Comment: @FlorianHartig in some cases the poisson can be a very good approximation to the binomial. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/561276/111259. Depends on if the prevalence pathogen is very high. If it isn’t, as the linked answer states, then the answers should be similar.

Comment: yes but why not use the appropriate model in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @FlorianHarting here. With a Binomial likelihood, it is easier to reason about how uncertainty in the underlying prevalence should grow as sample size decreases. For example, if you have 10 positives out of 20 sampled, your estimate of a prevalence ~ 50% will have uncertainty associated with it. But if you have 3 positives out of 6 sampled, the uncertainty should *grow*, as you correctly point out in your question. The Binomial likelihood automatically handles this variation in uncertainty for you, and your corresponding parameter estimates will accomodate correctly.

If you have remaining unmodelled dispersion, you can consider a Beta-Binomial (see this nice overview of how to do both in `brms`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_customfamilies.html). Of course there are other ways to do this, as @Demetri suggests, but in my opinion these are harder to think about and explain.